# Use pygmt in a IDE (spyder) with conda

Tags: installation, conda, spyder, environment, pygmt

I'm using spyder to make my codes.
I try to use pygmt lib but, in my spyder-env I have an error :

```
GMTCLibNotFoundError: Error loading GMT shared library at 'libgmt.so'.
libgmt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

According to the pygmt documentation, I have to create a new env to use this lib, so I did :

```
conda create --name pygmt --channel conda-forge pygmt

conda activate pygmt
```

But I have 2 problems :

1. spyder launch itself with the 3 version instead of 5 (as in my spyder-env/ typically).
2. Error stays :

   GMTCLibNotFoundError: Error loading GMT shared library at '/home/vialb/miniconda3/envs/pygmt/lib/libgmt.so'.
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/vialb/miniconda3/envs/pygmt/lib/./libgdal.so.31)
   Error loading GMT shared library at 'libgmt.so'.
   libgmt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm not familiar with environment so, I don't know what tot do with this...

Any idea ?

Comment: precision : in bash, using just python3 to launch  python interface, if I type "import pygmt", it seems to work. The problem could be spyder...

Answer (score 2):

Hum, not sure if I done something different, but that's working now, with this procedure :

1. on the (base) environnement, create pygmt env with :

   conda create --name pygmt --channel conda-forge pygmt
2. activate the new env :

   conda activate pygmt
3. install spyder

   conda install spyder

And ... That's all. Spyder open in version 5 and import pygmt works too.